# Sporadic stack pointer segmentation fault of forked process

Tags: c++, linux, process, embedded-linux

I am trying to debug a process which once in a while segmentation faults on access to the stack pointer.

The process used to segfault before the first line of main() {
Now the segfault moved to another place down the line.

If it does not crash, then the process will continue to run correctly indefinitely.

I am guessing that this is related to the way the process is instantiated:

```
pid_t COsAbstraction::Start(const uint32_t coreId, const char* argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    sigset_t mask;
    sigset_t save;

    /*
     * Block SIGCHLD
     */
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &save);

    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        _exit(false);
    }
    if (pid != 0)
    {
        // I am the parent
        pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &save, NULL);
        return pid;;
    }
    // I am the child
    // Replace myself with the desired process
    execvp(argv[ 0 ],  const_cast<char**>(argv))

    _exit(0);
```

}

Crashing code (sporadic):

```
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0804c663 <main+0>:    lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
0x0804c667 <main+4>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x0804c66a <main+7>:    pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
0x0804c66d <main+10>:   push   %ebp
0x0804c66e <main+11>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x0804c670 <main+13>:   push   %edi
0x0804c671 <main+14>:   push   %esi
0x0804c672 <main+15>:   push   %ebx
0x0804c673 <main+16>:   push   %ecx
0x0804c674 <main+17>:   sub    $0x525a8,%esp
0x0804c67a <main+23>:   call   0x804a22e <__i686.get_pc_thunk.bx>
0x0804c67f <main+28>:   add    $0x6125,%ebx
0x0804c685 <main+34>:   mov    (%ecx),%eax
0x0804c687 <main+36>:   mov    %eax,-0x52578(%ebp)
0x0804c68d <main+42>:   mov    0x4(%ecx),%ecx
0x0804c690 <main+45>:   mov    %ecx,-0x5257c(%ebp)
0x0804c696 <main+51>:   movl   $0x0,-0x418(%ebp)
0x0804c6a0 <main+61>:   movl   $0x400,0x8(%esp)
0x0804c6a8 <main+69>:   movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
0x0804c6b0 <main+77>:   lea    -0x410(%ebp),%eax
0x0804c6b6 <main+83>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0804c6b9 <main+86>:   call   0x8049c4c <memset@plt>

(gdb) info registers 
eax            0xf746d564       -146352796
ecx            0xf746d4e0       -146352928
edx            0xf746d500       -146352896
ebx            0x444a7ff4       1145733108
esp            0xf741af10       0xf741af10
ebp            0xf746d4c8       0xf746d4c8
esi            0x8050b30        134548272
edi            0x8049d90        134520208
eip            0x804c67a        0x804c67a <main+23>
eflags         0x210282 [ SF IF RF ID ]
cs             0x23     35
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x2b     43
es             0x2b     43
fs             0x0      0
```

This code runs on a 24 core RedHat Linux 2.6 device.

Update:

Turns out the crashes are not related to the calling process!
The simple "hello world" also crashes when hundreds of times from the shell:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char a[100*1024];
    a[0] = '1';
    printf("Hello There!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Should I submit a new question or modify this one?

Comment: So which line of code does it crash at?

Comment: It crashes right on the { of main() on get_pc_thunk. eip = 0x804c67a <main+23>. Newer crashes happen on a movl $0x04, 0x4(%esp). Trying to access the stack at that address causes the segfault. Once in a while a process is instantiated with the stack being too short.

Comment: This smells like bad RAM to me.

Comment: Or constructors of global scope objects, which run before `main()` is called...

Comment: So your hello world program crashes when run from the shell? Will it do so without the large char[] allocation? Obvious questions would be if the same binary runs without crashing on a more modest, compatible-ABI, machine, and if you see crashes in off-the-shelf prebuilt programs.  Also, have you tried a different compiler version?

Comment: Yes, the hello world crashes from shell. It's an ATCA chassis with different cards in the slots. It crashes on all the cards of the same type. It does not crash on other types of cards (dual core X86 or MIPS). We have not seen other crashes, but then they might not be allocating so much on the stack. We do not have another cross compiler for this platform. It looks like the stack does not grow automatically at times to the 8M limit.

Comment: If you are running Redhat Linux on the systems as you say, then you have many choices of versions of hosted compilers, and no need to confine yourself to cross compilers, at least on one you chose to dedicate for investigating this problem.  Note additionally that the test program you have posted is not allocating anywhere near a megabyte.

Comment: The test binary compiled for WR 3.0 runs on a WR 1.4 platform correctly. Looks like a problem with the platform or kernel. Time to call Windriver...

Answer (score 0):

The C program crashes because you're exiting from the stack of the program.

The point is that a variable like

```
char a[100*1024];
```

is allocated on the stack, it's size is limited and when you point to the beginning of the array you're exiting from the stack if the process.

To give you an example, I just modified the code because I'm on amd64, so I have

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char a[12*1024*1024];
    a[0] = '1';
    printf("Hello There!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

so I am trying to put a 12 MB variable in the stack. The default size of the stack as you can see is 8MB and when I try to execute it I get this:

```
ottavio@magritte:/tmp$ ulimit -s
8192
ottavio@magritte:/tmp$ ./x 
Segmentation fault
```

But if I increase the stack size it works

```
ottavio@magritte:/tmp$ ulimit -s 16384
ottavio@magritte:/tmp$ ./x 
Hello There!
ottavio@magritte:/tmp$
```

Comment: The default stack size 8Meg well above the 100K allocated in the example code. The crash happened once or twice in 500 runs. If the stack was too small it should have crashed every time.